# Automatically create PHP error_log file within same directory

Tags: php, error-handling

I have PHP 5.6 and I want PHP to automatically create error_log file within same directory.

[image: Error Log file]

I did the configuration as following in php.ini:

```
display_errors = Off
error_log = error_log
```

But nothing show up.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display maybe this can help.

Comment: @ParthGoswami this on is for in-page errors, not for files.